# Confused with articles

Tags: articles

I'm practicing articles and at the begining it seemed quite easy, but now i'm completely confused. Here are reasons:

> Several million visitors a year are attracted to **the** ski slopes of the
>   Alps.

As long as it's plural - there should be no article - I guess.

> I went to --- Buckingham Palace today. It was great.
>
> I took the train to London and then the underground to --- Victoria Station. It’s a short walk from there.
>
> If you ever go to London you must see the Tower of London and --- Tate Gallery.

There's one and only one (definite) Buckingam Palace (/Victoria Station / Tate Gallery). Whatmore it's name of building. Considering that - why it's without article?

> After his wife’s death he left --- home and joined the army.
>
> John himself doesn't go to ---- church.

Does both 'home' and 'church' are treated as 'general' here, and that's why no article?

> There will always be a conflict between the **old** and the **young**. ----- young people want ---- change

Isn't the old and young general thing and then should be left without article?

> It's right that there aren't so many ways of spending ---- daily life in **the** suburbs.

Why suburbs are so specific in this sentence?

I'm bit confused and hope for native english speakers or experienced learners it won't take much time to clarify my concerns.

Comment: Did you concoct the sentence on your own ? I mean, what is the source ?

*the computer, computer, and computers, and the computers can be used in a common sentence*. This depends on the writer's intents.

Comment: However, when there is a single thing in the world, especially a prominent one, usually the article is omitted. For example, name of the continents, famous land marks and so on

Comment: @Cardinal - I disagree.  The Louvre, the Taj Mahal, the Great Wall of China, the Washington Monument, the Leaning Tower of Pisa, the Pyramids...but then there is also Buckingham Palace, Fallingwater, Notre Dame, Stonehenge...  The best we can say is that it's inconsistent.

Comment: @stangdon yes, thanks for correcting me. I think *usually* is very strong adverb.

Comment: @Cardinal, sure I should be more precise. All examples are extracted from those files: http://goo.gl/x3GlRC and http://goo.gl/JfkIfs

It seems, that the easiest way to learn articles is to forget about them and hope to sound correct :-) I mean, do we really got confused if i say The Notre Dame? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of articles is a complex topic and can cover whole chapters in grammar books. I'll just go through your sentences.

> Several million visitors a year are attracted to **the** ski slopes of the Alps.

There's a definite article in front of “ski slopes” because the sentence is about a specific group of ski slopes: the ones in the Alps. If there it was just “∅ ski slopes”, it would mean “some ski slopes [but not all of them]”, and then the complement “of the Alps” would sound strange since it wouldn't be defining a set anymore. “∅ ski slopes in the Alps” would be fine; in that sentence, “attracted to the ski slopes of the Alps” implicitly designates all the ski slopes in the Alps, while “attracted to ∅ ski slopes in the Alps” makes it clear that only some ski slopes are attractive.

While we're at it, why “**the** Alps”? Most proper nouns don't take an article. But most *plural* proper nouns take the article *the*, and mountain ranges are plural (there may be exceptions but I can't think of one). *The Alps*, *the Andes*, *the Himalayas*, … Individual peaks normally don't take an article: *Mount Blanc*, *Mount Everest*, *Aconcagua*, …

> I went to **∅** Buckingham Palace today. It was great.
> I took the train to **∅** London and then the underground to **∅** Victoria Station. It’s a short walk from there.
> If you ever go to **∅** London you must see **the** Tower of London and **the** Tate Gallery.

The default rule for proper nouns is that they don't take an article. I highlighted a few more — *London* doesn't take an article.

Then we have **∅** Buckingham Palace vs. **the** Tate Gallery (the Tate Gallery does take an article). As a rule, people's homes (including official ones) don't take an article: ∅ Buckingham Palace, ∅ Mansion House, … Many other kinds of buildings don't take an article when their name is of the form <specific designation> <building type>, for example churches (*Westminster Abbey*), hospitals (*Mount Sinai Hospital*), and stations, airports and the like: ∅ Victoria Station, ∅ Heathrow Airport, ∅ Boston Harbor, ∅ British Museum (the former tube station), … But museums and monuments do take an article: the British Museum (the museum), the Tate Gallery, the Washington Monument, the Tower of London…

*The* Tower of London takes an article for another reason: it's phrased as a common noun with a qualifying complement. It's hard for *the* X of Y to lose its definite article, even if the clause as a whole becomes a proper noun. Likewise [*the* Port of London](http://www.pla.co.uk/Port-Trade/About-the-Port-of-London), [*the Port of Dover*](https://www.doverport.co.uk/) take an article. But there are exceptions, for example [*Port of Tyne*](https://www.portoftyne.co.uk/). Similarly, it's *the* White House, because *white* is an adjective here, not a name, so it's more like *the* house of X, although it's still a proper name so *House* is still capitalized.

> After his wife’s death he left **∅** home and joined the army.
> John himself doesn't go to ---- church.

*Home* and *church* in these contexts are general concepts and take the null article. It's rare for *home* to take a definite article (usually, in contexts that would require it, a word like *house* is used instead); *the church* means a specific building (“the church is being renovated”), and *the Church* is a religious institution (out of context, usually the Catholic Church).

> There will always be a conflict between **the** old and **the** young.

“The + adjective” means “people who are X”. More generally, it can mean the elements in an implicit category that satisfy the adjective, e.g. “predators catch the sick and the wounded” (implicit category: animals).

> **∅** Young people want **∅** change.

*People* in the sense of a collection of persons never takes a definite or indefinite article. “The people” and “the English people” are different meanings of the word *people*: a social or national grouping.

*Change* in this sentence takes the null article because the sentence is about the general concept. Young people want change in general, not a specific change.

> It's right that there aren't so many ways of spending **∅** daily life in **the** suburbs.

There is no article before “daily life” for the same reason as “change” above.

“The suburbs” is rather an exception to the general rules of articles. It's a set phrase, meaning peripheral areas of cities in general. I can't see a logic to it, but the usage is undisputed.

Comment: When you note that "the + [adjective]" is a separate case, it might help to give the name for such a construct: [a nominalized adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective).

Comment: @Gilles many thanks for your diligent work. I'll need some time to familiarize with your explanation but it is understandable now.

Comment: @Gilles you say transportation infrastructure does not take a definite article but then one says "I spend four hours a week on the London Underground." Can you please explain?

Comment: @Donbhupi Oh, I was only thinking of “point” infrastructure, not of networks and lines. Those do usually take an article: “the London underground”, “the Victoria line”. But “London underground” is not really a proper noun anymore and *underground* shouldn't be capitalized: it's just the underground of London. The proper name of the network may or may not have an article: it depends. *Transport for London* (the current name of the authority that oversees public transport in London) doesn't take an article, but “the New York City Transit Authoirty” does if you spell it out.